# Help to understand the usage of 'found' in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Stephanie Clifford, aka Stormy Daniels, is making the most of the fame she’s **found** from her alleged affair with President Donald Trump and is dishing details with her tell-all book “Full Disclosure.”

My confusion is out of the usage of the word "**found**" in this context, which seems to mean "**gained or got**". But I can't get any reference about this definition in dictionaries. I appreciate if someone can help to explain it and better with some more examples about it. Thanks a lot!

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/sports/stormy-daniels-writes-ben-roethlisberger-terrified-met-donald-trump-property-232300336.html).

Comment: Senses 2a, 2d, 3a, 3b, and 3d from Merriam-Webster's definition of [find](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/find) all seem relevant.

Comment: @JasonBassford yeah, I have gone through those similar definitions in other dictionaries too. But I found none of them are exactly the same as the way it's used in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To [find fame](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20found%20fame%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) (and fortune)** is something of a collocation.

To find fame is to [meet with](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meet+with+approval%2Cmeet+with+applause%2Cmeet+with+acclaim%2Cmet+with+acclaim%2Cmet+with+approval%2Cmet+with+applause&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmeet%20with%20approval%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmeet%20with%20applause%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmeet%20with%20acclaim%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmet%20with%20acclaim%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmet%20with%20approval%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmet%20with%20applause%3B%2Cc0) it, in the sense that we meet with approval or meet with applause, or meet with acclaim, that is, we are met with approval or are met with applause or are met with acclaim.  We *encounter* them.

Answer (score -1):

I think the word *found* is a perfect fit there. Why? Because the statement shows the fact that a not-so-famous person is ***finding*** an opportunity to get famous. Obviously, in this case, the famous is the President.

So, gain or get could be still *milder* as compared to *find* an opportunity. The latter one shows your desperation in getting something and of course your cleverness.

Comment: Any reasons for the downvoting?

Comment: @dan *hobby* of some users! :)